# Ubuntu clone does not load virtual NIC fast enough

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh

We have a Ubuntu virtual machine that was a clone of a production machine that some tests were being run on. This machine is a secure FTP server and as a security measure sshd is running using two different ports and IP addresses. The first IP address is for client access and uses port 22 the second address uses port 333. the second address is tied to a virtual nic. Like this:

```
eth0   - 192.168.1.4
eth0:1 - 192.168.1.5
```

NOTE These IP addresses are different than the production server.

When we reboot there is a "failed to start Raise network" error and the second instance of sshd does not start on port 333. However when you log into the console of the box and you run ifconfig the interface is up and all that has to be done is to fire off the second instance of sshd with the correct configuration file.

The issue we have is we do not know if the production machine is experiencing the same issue. It has not in the past but we have had a patching cycle since the last reboot so it was never tested to see if it will fail. It is just a timing issue how can I put in a delay or a depends on at boot?

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search my.domain.com
#       post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
       address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
       broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.255
       gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.1
```

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu are you running? Does it use systemd for startup? Have you tried configuring multiple IP addresses on the same eth0, *without* using "alias interfaces"?

Comment: We are using 18.04. I inherited this machine and I have no idea what has been tried in the past. As I said the original machine has rebooted multiple times with no issue. Now it has started exhibiting an issue. I have no idea if the last patching broke this function.

Comment: Not addressing the question, but correcting a widespread misunderstanding: on Linux an alias interface, despite its name, is not a virtual interface, but an additional address on an interface, with a label attached. It exists only for compatibility with older tools (`ifconfig` whose obsolete kernel API can't configure more than one IPv4 address per interface, instead of `ip address`). There's no additional interface: routing doesn't know of an additional "interface", firewall can't match this "interface" because it's not an interface etc.

Comment: @A.B Thank you for that insight. This I did not know for sure. There was no MAC address for the second IP address and that confused me. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `/bin/sleep 30` to the top of the startup script for the second sshd instance. This has done the trick.